# Error: Can't bind name in null syntactic environment

Tags: scheme, sicp

I'm currently going through exercise 1.3 of the sicp book. Here's the description of the problem:

> Define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns
>   the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers.

I tried to solve it with the following code

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (sq2largest a b c)
        ((define large1 (if (> a b) a b)) 
         (define small  (if (= large1 a) b a))
         (define large2 (if (> c small) c small))
         (+ (square large1) (square large2))))
```

When I ran it in mit-scheme, I got the following error:

> ;Can't bind name in null syntactic environment: large1
>   #[reserved-name-item 13]

Googling this error doesn't yield many results. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? (I'm not familiar with Scheme)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many brackets. If you took out the extra brackets around the internal defines, things should work a lot better.

Comment: Removing the internal parentheses did work, but I don't understand how that solves the problem. The syntax of define is (define <id> <expr>). I thought that I would have to group everything under <expr> together, hence the extra pair of parentheses.

Comment: @KietTran The basic `define` form is indeed `(define <id> <expr>)`. But you're using a variation for defining functions, `(define (<id> <arguments>) <body>)`. You had extra parens for the `<body>` part. By the way, this second variation for defining functions is simply sugar for the primary form: It's shorthand for `(define <id> (lambda (<arguments>) <body>)`. In other words, "defining a function" means defining a variable whose value is a `lambda` instead of (say) a number or string.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to break down the structure of your sq2largest procedure:

The basic structure is:

```
(define (sq2largest a b c)
    ; Body)
```

The Body you wrote is:

```
((define large1 (if (> a b) a b)) ; let this be alpha
 (define small  (if (= large1 a) b a)) ; let this be bravo
 (define large2 (if (> c small) c small)) ; let this be charlie
 (+ (square large1) (square large2)) ; let this be delta) ; This parentheses encloses body
```

So, the Body is structured as:

```
(alpha bravo charlie delta)
```

Which translates to: "Pass bravo, charlie and delta as arguments to alpha."

Now, alpha is being told to take a bunch of arguments, *but* inside the namespace reserved for large1, no provision was made for any argument... i.e. scheme encounters a null syntactic environment where it cannot bind any variable.

Parentheses are significant in Scheme (and most, if not all, Lisps) because they define the scope of a procedure and enforce[1] the order of application of operations.

[1] "No ambiguity can arise, because the operator is always the leftmost element and the entire combination is delimited by the parentheses." http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node6.html